# Terms interpretation of differential equation system?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems, mathematical-modeling

> If $N(t)$ = quantity of nicotine at time $t$ in the lung,
>
> $C(t)=$ number of smoked cigarettes at time $t$,
>
> How to interprete each term of the model correctly? $$N'(t)=\beta N-\alpha NC$$ $$C'(t)=\alpha NC-\delta C$$

**This is what I did:** I am not sure in this term $\alpha NC$.

$N'(t)$=The rate at which the amount of nicotine in the lung changes at time t.

$\beta N$=Rate at which  amount of nicotine is ingested at time t.

$-\alpha NC$=Rate at which nicotine decreases due to lack of cigarettes.

$C'(t)=$Rate at wich the number of smoked cigars changes.

$\alpha NC$=Rate at which nicotine increase due to cigarettes.??

$-\delta C$=Rate at which the use of cigarettes decreases.

Comment: This model doesn't make any sense at all to me. If $C$ is large (you smoke a lot a cigarettes), the amount of nicotine in your lung *decreases*? And (the rate of change of) the number of cigarettes that you smoke depends on how much nicotine you *already* have in your lung?!?

Comment: I'm having trouble with the notion of a "correct interpretation" being something we can resolve by reasoned mathematical argument.  After all we don't know anything about the underlying phenomenon to be modelled, or about the parameters $\alpha,\beta,\delta$ used in the equations.

Comment: @hardmath it turns out the model it's not stated correctly (not my fault I found it on google), therefore It can't have a correct interpretation.

Comment: @hardmath however, it could have been resolved by reasoned mathematical argument, if it had been stated correctly

Comment: Okay, good effort.

Answer (score 2):

You are forgetting the most central effect: Cigarette consumption brings nicotine into the lung. As this obviously has to depend on $C$, the only candidate for this is $-\alpha NC$. However, the sign on this is unusual, so we can expect more weird sign down the road. I also have no idea why this would depend on $N$. Is there some self-enhancing effect, i.e., the amount of nicotine in the lung increase the absorption somehow?

At the same time, the amount of nicotine consumed decreases the desire to consume more and thus the cigarette consumption, which leads to $\alpha NC$ in the second equation.

The remaining terms would then be the amount with which the body disposes nicotine ($\beta N$) and how much the addiction increase the desire to smoke ($-δN$).

The above is the only way I can make some sense of this.
However, without further explanation and given the weird signs, I do not find the model very convincing.
I would rather guess that somebody has taken the [Lotka–Volterra model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lotka%E2%80%93Volterra_equations) and blindly translated it.

Comment: I suspect that too, that the model was somehow wrong, however I was not sure and that's why I asked here.